# Query Dynamics CRM records by conection role

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I need to find all the contacts that are connected to a account via a Connection Role Pair.  In SQL it looks like this...

```sql
SELECT ConnectionRoleBase.Name AS [Account Name], ContactBase.FullName AS [Conection Role], AccountBase.Name AS [Contact Name]
FROM ConnectionBase INNER JOIN
ConnectionRoleBase ON ConnectionBase.Record2RoleId = ConnectionRoleBase.ConnectionRoleId INNER JOIN
ContactBase ON ConnectionBase.Record2Id = ContactBase.ContactId INNER JOIN
AccountBase ON ConnectionBase.Record1Id = AccountBase.AccountId
WHERE(ConnectionRoleBase.Name LIKE N'%scientist%')
```

Can I do this using Odata?  If so I'm not sure how to write the query because connections are not like other entities.

Can I use FetchXML?  Again what how do I reference the Connection?

I need to query this from JavaScript a would prefer to use the XRMTServicesToolKit and Odata.  Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OData for this.  The tables are ConnectionSet, ConnectionRoleSet, AccountSet, and ContactSet.  You would need to do nested calls to do all of the required joins.

I prefer the CRMRestKit for doing OData queries, as I find it simplifies writing the query, but whatever tool you like should suffice.  It would require using the ByQuery (aka RetrieveMultiple) in combination with Retrieve (aka retrieve individual).